# Horizontal Scroll Recyclerview in Vertical Recyclerview with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-viewpager2

I am building an application that uses a `ViewPager2` to scroll horizontally across pages that each have a vertically scrolling content `RecyclerView` where the first position of each list has a row with a Horizontally scrolling widget such as another `RecyclerView` or `ViewPager2` attached to a Pager Indicator type widget as seen from the below image.

The parent ViewPager2 is a child of a CoordinatorLayout that handles collapsing the top content when the RecyclerView is scrolled Vertically. This ViewPager2 then inflates fragments that are horizontally scrolling.  So we have for the `parent layout`:

```
-- CoordinatorLayout 
   -- FrameLayout - has appbar scrolling behavior 
      -- ViewPager2
   -- AppBarLayout
      -- CollapsingToolbarLayout
         -- ImageView - background
         -- Toolbar
         -- ConstraintLayout - Holds title and date
```

The parent ViewPager2 `child fragments' layout`:

```
-- FrameLayout
   -- RecyclerView
   -- Pager Indicator
```

The first row of the content RecyclerView has the same layout:

```
-- FrameLayout
   -- RecyclerView
   -- Pager Indicator
```

[image: Unscrolled state]

You can see from the above screenshot that on first load the `RecyclerView` is overlapping the `AppBarLayout` which is the correct behavior. I added negative `marginTop` to `RecyclerView`'s parent layout to achieve this effect. I am tracking the AppBarLayout offset changes with a `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` and as the user scrolls up I am reducing or increasing this negative margin to have the list animate under the `AppBarLayout`.

The problem I am facing is if I start a vertical scroll from the first item in the list then the `AppBarLayout` is not getting triggered to start collapsing its content so the content ends up prematurely under the `AppBarLayout`. See the following screenshot:

[image: RecyclerView incorrect scroll]

I want the AppBarLayout content to start scrolling up as soon as I start the 
 content RecyclerView scroll even if it is initiated from the first position. It seems that the first item's `RecyclerView` is not alerting the `AppBarLayout` to start collapsing. If I start the scroll from other items in the RecyclerView the correct behavior is observed. If I drag up and hold from the first row then the bug is also observed.

A good example of the behavior I am trying to achieve is the Google News App where there is a tab of news sections. The following is what I am expecting:

[image: Correct vertical scroll animation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple. If you have a nested RecyclerView or similar container then you have to use:

```
RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

i read through the offered answer(s) of using setNestedScrollingEnabled to false and it was awful for me as it makes the recyclerview not recycle and you can get crashes in memory, etc if you have a huge list.  so i will give you a algorithm to make it work without confusing the coordinatorLayout.

1. have a scroll listener on the vertical recyclerview, such as a scroll listener. anytime the list is scrolled you will get a callback that its being *scrolled*. you should also get a call back when its *idle*.
2. now when vertical recylerview is being *scrolled*, setNestedScrollingEnabled = false on the horizontal list.
3. once vertical recyclerview is idle setNestedScrollingEnabled = true on the horizontal list.
4. also initially set the horizontal recyclerview to setNestedScrollingEnabled = false in xml

summary: essentially toggling off nested scrolling when user is scrolling vertically.

this work great with appbarlayout when coordinatorlayout gets confused with two recyclerviews in different directions.